# Secondary database connection with Doctrine 2 and ZF2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to add a extra connection to my doctrine configuration. my orm_default connection works perfectly fine, and now I'm trying to add a new module with its own Doctrine configuration (mostly learning purposes, buts its rather annoying that I can't get it to work).

The module is called Frontpage, and all relevant code is in this one, except for username/password details that resides in local.php...

My error is

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException
An exception was raised while creating "doctrine.entitymanager.orm_hosts"; no instance returned
```

Also further down the stacktrace (the last exception) which I think is relevant, but don't know how to fix...

```
Zend\Stdlib\Exception\BadMethodCallException
The option "hydration_cache" does not have a matching setHydrationCache setter method which must be defined
```

Here is my module config (relevant parts) file:

```
'doctrine' => [
    'connection' => [
        'orm_hosts' => [
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
            'params' => [
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => '3306',
                'dbname' => 'hosts',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'entitymanager' => array(
        'orm_hosts' => array(
            'connection'    => 'orm_hosts',
            'configuration' => 'orm_hosts'
        )
    ),
    'configuration' => array(
        'orm_hosts' => array(
            'driver'            => 'orm_hosts',
            'generate_proxies'  => true,
            'proxy_dir'         => 'data/DoctrineORMModule/Proxy',
            'proxy_namespace'   => 'DoctrineORMModule\Proxy',
            'filters'           => array(),
            'metadata_cache'    => 'array',
            'query_cache'       => 'array',
            'result_cache'      => 'array',
            //'hydration_cache'   => 'array',
        )
    ),

    'driver' => array(
        'orm_hosts' => array(
            'class'   => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DriverChain',
            'drivers' => array(
                'Common\Entity' =>  'Hosts_Driver'
            )
        ),
        'Hosts_Driver' => array(
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/../src/Common/Entity'
            )
        ),
    ),
    'eventmanager' => array(
        'orm_hosts' => array()
    ),

    'sql_logger_collector' => array(
        'orm_hosts' => array(),
    ),

    'entity_resolver' => array(
        'orm_hosts' => array()
    ),
],
```

And my Module.php's getServiceConfig():

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'doctrine.connection.orm_hosts'           => new Service\DBALConnectionFactory('orm_hosts'),
            'doctrine.configuration.orm_hosts'        => new Service\ConfigurationFactory('orm_hosts'),
            'doctrine.entitymanager.orm_hosts'        => new Service\EntityManagerFactory('orm_hosts'),

            'doctrine.entity_resolver.orm_hosts'      => new Service\EntityResolverFactory('orm_hosts'),
            'doctrine.sql_logger_collector.orm_hosts' => new Service\SQLLoggerCollectorFactory('orm_hosts'),
            'doctrine.driver.orm_hosts'               => new \DoctrineModule\Service\DriverFactory('orm_hosts'),
            'doctrine.eventmanager.orm_hosts'         => new \DoctrineModule\Service\EventManagerFactory('orm_hosts'),

            'DoctrineORMModule\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder\orm_hosts' => function(\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $sl) {
                return new \DoctrineORMModule\Form\Annotation\AnnotationBuilder($sl->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_hosts'));
            },
        ),
    );
}
```

And here is my getEntityManager() in IndexController that fails

```
/**
 * @return array|EntityManager|object
 */
public function getEntityManager() {
    if (NULL === $this->em) {
        /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em */
        $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_hosts');
        //$em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('doctrine')->getManager("orm_hosts");
        $this->em = $em;
    }
    return $this->em;
}
```

Any help will be gratly appreciated :)

Best regards
Richard

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I still don't know what is wrong with the above code, but if I remove

```
'Hydration_cache' => 'array'
```

In the doctrine configuration from my module config, it actually works! Still, if anyone want's to explain what happens, I would appreciate to know more :)